# How to map only single column with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to join a single column from another table to one of my `@Entity` classes:

Currently it works as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id 
    private long id; //autogenerated

    String type; //used for mapping

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    ProductMapping mapping;
}

@Entity
public class ProductMapping {
    @Id
    String type;
    
    String longname;
}
```

Question: how could I replace the `@ManyToOne` mapping to directly map to `String longname`?

```
//TODO: how to directly map to 'mapping.longname'?
@JoinColumn(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
String mapping.longname;
```

Comment: It wouldn't remove the @ManyToOne, but perhaps add `longname` to `Product` as `transient`, with it's getters/setters delegating to `mapping`.

Comment: There is the SecondaryTable annotation but this only works for OneToOne https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-mapping-single-entity-to-multiple-tables

Comment: @AndrewS that's a great workaround!

Comment: @SimonMartinelli unfortunately I have to string with many to one mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@Formula** annotation with a query like this :

```
@Formula("(select pm.longname from product_mapping pm where pm.COL_NAME = value)")
private String longName;

//give the column name of type from product_mapping table
```

**OR**

You can also use the below approach :

```
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)   
 @JoinColumn(name = "type", referencedColumnName = "COL_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 ProductMapping mapping;
```

The other entity use **@NaturalId** annotation on the field.

```
@Entity
public class ProductMapping {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    String type;
    
    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "SOME_VALUE")
    String longname;
}
```